# PyTelegramBotAPI forward last post from channel to user_id

Tags: python-3.x, bots, telegram, telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

how can i get update from channel message id?

```
  @bot.channel_post_handler(func=lambda call: True)
  def channel():

      bot.forward_message(user_id, '@bot_username', message_id)
```

my bot is a admin in channel

#sorry i use stackoverflow firstly

Answer (score 1):

As I understood, you want to forward new channel posts to the user, but don't know how to get the `message_id` of the new channel post

If so, then you can do like this:

```py
@bot.channel_post_handler(func=lambda m: True)
def handle_posts(m: telebot.types.Message):
    bot.forward_message(12345, m.chat.id, m.message_id)
```

What this handler does is forwards any new channel post to the user with id `12345`

We are obtaining message and chat IDs from the `Message` object which comes from the `channel_post_handler` and passed to the `handle_posts` function as `m`